# WPF запускать разную анимацию в зависимости от размера окна

Tags: wpf, xaml

кнопка должна увеличивать/уменьшать окно

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="expandWnd"
        AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="wndw"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(Window.Height)"
                         To="300" 
                         Duration="0:0:1"
                         >
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="shrinkWnd"
        AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="wndw"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(Window.Height)"
                         To="120" 
                         Duration="0:0:1"
                         >
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource expandWnd}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

как запустить `shrinkWnd` если окно развернуто?

Comment: `<Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Minimized"> ... </Trigger>`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в коде высота окна а не состояние